# C# Is it possible to use an DB object reference in a static method?

Tags: c#, static

public abstract class AbstractDBConnector
    {
        private AdServiceDB db;

```
    public AdServiceDB Adapter
    {
        get 
        {
            if (db == null) db = new AdServiceDB();
            return db;
        }
    }
}
```

and a class that inherits from it:

```
public class BaseDataValidator : AbstractDBConnector
{
    public static bool Check()
    {
        var t = Adapter.Users.Where(x=>x.Id<10).ToList(); //the error is here
        return true; //example
    }
}
```

this code obviously generates an error: **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property** Is it even possible to do a trick to use the Adapter in the static method ?

Answer (score 1):

Only if Adapter is also `static`, which you probably don't want it to be (but maybe you do, I'm not sure what the exact use case is, there's not enough info).  Pass the adapter to the method as a parameter if the method must be `static`, but it seems more likely that your method just shouldn't be `static` in the first place.

EDIT: note that for the "make it `static` approach to work you'll have to make both `Adapter` and `db` `static`.

Comment: OK, but if I set Adapter as a static property, then (IMO) it shouldnt be used in a Web project (in the nearest foture it will be).

Comment: Yes.  That's why I started off stating that that was probably a bad idea, and it takes you back to my original suggestion of either having the method not be static at all or passing the adapter to it.